# C++ casting a single element of a string

Tags: c++, casting

I have recently tried to convert an element of a string (built from digits only) to int and in order to avoid bizzare results (like 49 instead of 1) I had to use 'stringstream' (not even knowing what it is and how it works) instead of `int variable = static_cast<int>(my_string_name[digit_position]);`.

According to what I've read about these 'streams' the type is irrelevant when you use them so I guess that was the case. The question is: **What type did I actually want to convert FROM and why didn't it work?** I thought that a string element is a char but apparently not if the conversion didn't work.

Comment: Do you want the char representation as a number or the stored digit?

Comment: `'1'` is not the value 1, but (most likely) the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value 49 which represents the character 1. To convert an ASCII digit character to its decimal value (i.e. `'0'` to `0`, `'1'` to `1`, etc.) just do `ascii_value - '0'`.

Comment: _"I had to use 'stringstream' (not even knowing what it is and how it works)"_ Programming by guessing doesn't work. You should have _found out_ what it is and how it works, by reading reference and instructional material.

Comment: Furthermore, you need to get out of the habit of using "it didn't work" as your problem statements. (Irony detected!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that a string element is a char but apparently not if the conversion didn't work.

Yes, it is a char. However, the value of this char is not how it is rendered on the screen. This actually depends on the encoding of the string. For example, if your string is encoded in ASCII, you can see that the "bizarre" 49 value that you got must have been represented as a `'1'` character. Building on that, you can subtract the ASCII code of the character `'0'` to get the numeric values of these characters. However, **be very careful**: this greatly depends on your encoding. It is possible that your string may use multi-byte characters when you can't even index them this naively.

Answer (score 2):

`char` values are already numeric, such a `static_cast` won't help you much here. What you actually need is:

```
int variable = my_string_name[digit_position] - '0';
```

For ASCII values the digits `'0' - '9'` are encoded as decimal numbers from `49 - 59`. So to get the numerical value that is represented by the digit we need to substract the 1st digits value of 49.

To make the code portable for other character encoding tables (e.g. EBCDIC) the `'0'` is substracted.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are looking for is not a cast, but the `std::stoi` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function, which converts a string representation of an integer to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a string: `std::string myString("1");`. You could access the first element which is type `char` and you convert it to type `int` via `static_cast`. However, your expectation of what will happen is incorrect.

Upon looking at the [ASCII table for number `1`](http://www.ascii-code.com/) you will see it has a base 10 integer value of `49`, which is why the cast gives the output you're seeing. Instead you could use a conversion function like [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) (e.g., `atoi(&myString[0]);`).

Answer (score 0):

Your "bizzare results" aren't actually that bizzare. When accessing a single character of a `std::string` like so : `my_string_name[digit_position]` you're getting a `char`. Putting that `char` in an `int` will convert '1' to an `int`. Looking at http://www.asciitable.com/ we can see that 49 is the representation for '1'. To get the actual number you should do `int number = my_string_name[digit_position] - '0';`

Answer (score 0):

You are working with the ASCII char code for a number, not an actual number. However because the ASCII char codes are [laid out in order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters):

48. `'0'`
49. `'1'`
50. `'2'`
51. `'3'`
52. `'4'`
53. `'5'`
54. `'6'`
55. `'7'`
56. `'8'`
57. `'9'`

So if you are converting a single character and you're character is in base-10 then you can use:

```
int variable = my_string_name[digit_position] - '0'
```

But this depends upon the use of character codes which are in sequence. Specifically, if there were any other characters interspersed here this wouldn't work at all (I don't know any character code mapping that doesn't have these listed sequentially.)

But to guarantee the conversion you should use [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
int variable = stoi(my_string_name.substr(digit_position, 1))
```